# How do I modify objects within objects using jq while keeping all other objects unchanged?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json object with a collection of additional objects.

Using `jq` I need to be able to modify some of the objects while keeping the others unchanged.

I keep running into issues where I can get the change, but then all the other objects disappear. Or I make the change but it impacts every other object.

Here is a sample json

```
{
  "AAAA": {
    "VALUES": {
      "val_1": {
        "key": "A_KEY1"
      },
      "val_2": {
        "key": "A_KEY2"
      }
    }
  },
  "BBBB": {
    "VALUES": {
      "val_a": {
        "key": "KEY1",
        "old": [ 0, 1 ]
      },
      "val_b": {
        "key": "KEY2",
        "old": [ 2, 3 ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am looking to get is no change to the `AAAA` object, however for each value in `BBBB.VALUES` I want to take the second value from the `old` array and create a new key value say "new"

```
{
  "AAAA": {
    "VALUES": {
      "val_1": {
        "key": "A_KEY1"
      },
      "val_2": {
        "key": "A_KEY2"
      }
    }
  },
  "BBBB": {
    "VALUES": {
      "val_a": {
        "key": "KEY1",
        "old": [ 0, 1 ],
        "new": 1
      },
      "val_b": {
        "key": "KEY2",
        "old": [ 2, 3 ],
        "new": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The array is guaranteed to be two elements long, the array does not need to be modified.

I've tried many incantations of `jq` and just can't seem to get it to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ keys[] ]` to iterate over the keys under `BBBB.VALUES` :

```
jq '(.BBBB.VALUES | . [ keys[] ]) |= .+  { new: .old[1] }' data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If one understands `with_entries/1`, an easy-to-read solution is possible:

```
.BBBB.VALUES
|= with_entries( .value.new = .value.old[1] ) )
```

Or more briefly:

```
.BBBB.VALUES
|= with_entries( .value |= (.new = .old[1] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **map_values**

```
.BBBB.VALUES |= map_values(.new = .old[1])
```